# Linux file with 0 size but has data

Tags: linux, file, filesystems, directory, mount-point

There is an existing linux server which has a mount,when I ls on that mount location its a file with 0 size. But the original location has files under it.

```
>df
/dev/mapper/Data2-INT_Internal
                     140493728 123468868   9888196  93% /data/int/internal
```

Here you see `/data/int/internal` path is mapped to `/dev/mapper/Data2-INT_Internal`, but when I go to `/dev/mapper/Data2-INT_Internal` location, its a file with 0 size. How is that possible because there is lot of data under `/data/int/internal`.

```
intmeta01:/dev/mapper> ls -l Data2-MAD_Internal
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 251, 0 2013-02-26 16:55 Data2-MAD_Internal
```

Please help me resolving this mystery.

Answer (score 1):

The file you are looking at is a block device. You can tell by the `b` in front of the permissions.

Block devices are basically just named entry points or handles. The device file itself doesn't "contain" data in any meaningful sense, it just points to some driver that can handle requests.

The `251, 0` you see is the major and minor device number, which tells the kernel which driver or subsystem should handle requests. Neither is a file size.